# python - how to list to installed pachage using python

Tags: python

I want connect to the /var/lib/dpkg/status to query what are the installed packages. The library should be python-apt but I am not sure. Anyone could help me ?
I Need to do this process manually because the script must be run from livecd on the hard disk.
thank u

Comment: _'how to list to installed pachage using python'_ Do you mean 'how to list the installed packages that use python' or 'how to programmatially (using python) list the installed packages' or something else?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using the Python APT API:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import apt
cache = apt.Cache()
for pkg in cache:
    if pkg.is_installed:
        print(pkg)
```

This uses the [`apt.cache`](https://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/library/apt.cache.html) (which contains information about the current package management state, including installation status) and [`apt.package`](https://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/library/apt.package.html) (details on a specific package) objects.

Comment: As I said it will run from livecd that means it will not work because the hard disk will not be chrooted.. I means /var/lib/dpkg/status will be on /mnt/var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: @user228943 then how do you expect `/var/lib/dpkg/status ` to exist? O.o

Comment: yes ofcourse it does not exist... it's just an example

Comment: @user228943 take a moment to read the documentation to `apt.cache`, linked in my answer, which mentions a `rootdir` parameter.

Comment: Thank you... yes I found it just now opening the cache.py file